# Paging through different diagrams in a table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I'm looking for a method to page or slide through up to 6 different views in one table view cell. What's the best approach to do that?

I already experiment with a Collection View and a Page View Control. But the diagrams are represented by different classes, so that the standard tutorials setting up a label, are not working for me.

Thank for any feedback on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you are doing, I would use a UICollectionView with different UICollectionViewCells for your different diagrams. That should allow you to use different classes for the content of each cell.

So first go and create a UICollectionViewCell for each diagram.

Then you are going to want to go into your UICollectionViewController (or wherever you are implementing your collection view) and in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method tell it which cell to display for each indexPath.